# How to return Array of Objects using Powermock and mockito

Tags: mockito, powermock

I have a method which return array of object.

`public IConfigurationElement[] getConfigurationElementsFor(String extensionPointId);`

I am not sure how can I mock this call using mockito and powermock.

I have tried

`mockConfigurationElements = (IConfigurationElement[]) Mockito.anyListOf( IConfigurationElement.class ).toArray();`

but this is ending in `ClassCastException`.

Comment: I have tried Mockito.any() and Mockito.anyListOf().toArray();

Comment: Are you mocking a final class? Why use PowerMock?

Comment: I am mocking some other class as well with static functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mocking (stubbing) calls with `Mockito` is done in a following way (for example):

```
Mockito.when(mockObject.getConfigurationElementsFor(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(new IConfigurationElement[]{})
```

or

```
Mockito.doReturn(new IConfigurationElement[]{}).when(mockObject).getConfigurationElementsFor(Mockito.anyString());
```

*Mockito.anyListOf()* is a use of a matcher. Matchers are passed instead of real arguments when stubbing meaning that the behavior is to be applied if the method is called with arguments satisfying those matchers.

Comment: Another thing you can do is create an actual array and populate it with mock objects.